# DreamEdit component converted to Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, components

I am using the DreamEdit (source code editing) component (of which I have a license and the source). 
Sadly, the company behind it (DreamCompany) stopped supporting and upgrading the component some years ago.

Has anyone been using this component too ? And more importantly, has anyone upgraded this component to Delphi 2009 or Delphi 2010 ?

I am willing to pay any reasonable price for this upgrade to Delphi 2010.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give an update on my own question: I looked around some further, found SyntEdit (note the t after Syn, so this is NOT SynEdit), downloaded it, tried it out under Delphi-2010 and bought a license.

It really does seem to fill my needs, is still maintained and is compatible with Delphi-2010 (the main reason why I was looking for another component suite than DreamEdit).

If anyone should be interested: it can be found here:
http://www.econtrol.ru/syntedit.html.

Thanks for all answers ... Erik

Answer (score 1):

I tried to convert it myself but didn't have much luck because of all the Unicode differences, so in the end just decided to convert to SynEdit.

SynEdit is Unicode-enabled and provides much the same functionality as Dream Memo does.  It's at http://synedit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: A couple of years back, when I choose DreamEdit, I tried SynEdit (and a few others) too. At that time it had some really anoying 'qualities'. I can't remember which, but one of them, if I am not mistaken, was that the width of the characters was not the same in bold and normal state (even in fixed fonts), resulting in realy annoying displays. Don't know if this is still the case.

Comment: @Alan Clark: did you install and use the Unicode SynEdit version  found on the mh-nexus.de web site ? No problems ? The regular SynEdit only provides packages up to Delphi-2006.

Comment: That's the one I installed yes, no problems so far.  It was a bit of a learning curve to convert our custom parser to SynEdit because the way that's done is very different, but it works the same in the end.

Answer (score 1):

LMD SyntaxEdit can be reasonable replacement form DreamEdit - take a look - http://lmd.de/products/vcl/lmdsyntaxedit/

Answer (score 0):

I use TMS [AdvMemo](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advmemo.asp)

Comment: I am downloading the demo as I type this. I am still hoping that someone has converted DreamEdit to Delphi 2010, but if not, I need something that is maintained. The last version of  SynEdit is from almost 2,5 years ago, and as I said in my previous comments:  I had some major reservations on it. But I will look into AdvMemo, thanks for the suggestion.